# What do I do with Human cargo?

Tags: out-there

In a star system I visited I encountered an abandoned ship with many humans aboard sleeping in cryogenic chambers. Is there anything I can or should be doing with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you complete a game, there's a stat for "Humans Saved." The more humans you bring to an ending, the higher that will be.

One of the endings *requires* you to bring humans:

> The Yellow ending, restarting human civilization on a newly-terraformed planet, requires you to bring some humans in cryogenic containers. Bring along at least one full stack of humans, because there's no point in bringing half a stack. I assume that bringing extra humans increases your score, but I don't know what the scoring algorithm is, and [the first wiki I found](http://out-there.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=score&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns14=1#) doesn't know either.

Other than that, humans have no purpose except to take up space in your hold.